# Does pytest parametrized test work with unittest class based tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I've been trying to add parametrized `@pytest.mark.parametrize` tests to a class based unittest.

```
class SomethingTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(('one', 'two'), [
        (1, 2), (2, 3)])
    def test_default_values(self, one, two):
        assert one == (two + 1)
```

But the parametrized stuff didn't *kick in*:

```
TypeError: test_default_values() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

I've switched to simple class based tests (without unittest). But I'd like to know if anyone tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [pytest documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html):

> *unittest.TestCase* methods cannot directly receive fixture function
>   arguments as implementing that is likely to inflict on the ability to
>   run general *unittest.TestCase* test suites.

Answer (score 16):

There's a simple workaround to parameterize unittest-based Python tests by using "parameterized": https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/

Here's a simple example. First install "parameterized": `pip install parameterized==0.9.0`

```
import unittest
from parameterized import parameterized

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @parameterized.expand([
        ["One", "Two"],
        ["Three", "Four"],
        ["Five", "Six"],
    ])
    def test_parameterized(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(arg1, arg2)
```

Now you can easily run your code with `pytest`

I've successfully used this technique to parameterize selenium browser tests that use the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework on GitHub in [this example](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/parameterized_test.py).

Comment: Note that, to use mocks, you should decorate behind the @parametrized and should "collect" the mock at the end of the args list (`arg3` maybe). I just tried it.

Comment: this doesn't solve the need to indirect parameterization, though :/

Comment: I am getting error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: I'm using 0.8.1 and it needs a LIST of the function arguments for each test, provided in a TUPLE format. E.g. my function takes one input so I'm doing:
`@parameterized.expand([(20.0,), (0.0,)])`