# Py.test: parametrize test cases from classes

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest

I'm currently following this [py.test](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html) example and it works out when I do not use classes, however when I introduce test cases into classes I am failing.

The smallest case I managed to write is the following:

```
import unittest

import pytest

class FixtureTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
    ])
    def test_1(self, a, b):
        self.assertEqual(a, b)
```

unfortunately when I execute

```
  py.test  test_suite.py
```

I get the error message:

```
  TypeError: test_1() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I do in order to generate a battery of test_1 tests?

Comment: Does your class need to be a subclass of `TestCase`?

Comment: Currently, it is not mandatory, what I need is to parametrize tests that are defined into a class

Comment: As for parametrized tests that `TestCase` methods, the answer to this older question appears to be still valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182251/does-pytest-parametrized-test-work-with-unittest-class-based-tests In short: mixing the two concepts won't work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you subclass from `unittest.TestCase`, your test methods cannot have additional arguments.  If you simply subclass from `object`, it will work (though you'll have to use regular `assert` statements instead of the `TestCase.assertEqual` methods.

```
import unittest

import pytest

class TestCase(object):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
    ])
    def test_1(self, a, b):
        assert eval(a) == b
```

At that point though, it kind of begs the question why you're using classes instead of just defining functions, since the test will essentially be the same, but require less overall boilerplate and code.

Comment: Sorry, I also meant to indicate that the class name needs to start with `Test` as well for pytest to pick it up.

Comment: I've just accepted the answer, however I was wondering whether there would be also an option when the class inherits from unittest.TestCase?

Comment: You won't be able to use `parametrize`.  The [docs](http://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html) link from @ThomasLotze explains it.  They provide some possibilities for hacking around the limitation, which in your case will likely involve setting test values on the class, and then looping though it in your test function to run a test with multiple test values.

Comment: There is a reason why I wonder that, in case it is not possible I will need to reimplement a number of test classes.

Comment: What if I was using TestCase so I could use the setUp etc functions?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this was the case 5 years ago, but these days you can use parameterized (https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/) with pytest to decorate test methods on a test class, yes including unittest.TestCase, without having to resort to nose. E.g.:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from parameterized import parameterized

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    @parameterized.expand([
        (1, 2),
        ('a', 'b')
    ])
    def test_something(self, param1, param2):
        ...
```

The only gotcha, but you better remember this, is that the decorator will generate new test methods for each listed input parameter, so you will not be able to run your original test method directly by specifying it on the command line. E.g. `pytest some_test.py::SomeTestCase::test_something` won't work anymore (because your test method now expects two parameters). However, you can call the generated methods directly, for which you can get the name from either the pytest error output when you run the whole TestCase or by doing a `pytest --collect-only`.

Comment: this is a nice solution if not using TestCase is an onerous option

Comment: You can run the test in "almost" this way: `pytest some_test.py::SomeTestCase::test_something` . You can add a `assert False` inside the test, and run the hole class to see the name generated by parameterized. The name is the test chained with the test index and the parameters, so to run the first test it will be something like: `pytest some_test.py::SomeTestCase::test_something_0_1_2`. Then if you want to run all tests, yes you have to run the hole class.

Comment: @Gonzalo This works, but how is this simpler or better than running pytest with `--collect-only` as I've described above? (E.g. `pytest --collect-only some_test.py::SomeTestCase`) Also, if just some of your parameterized cases fail, you will have the names automatically without forcing all the cases to fail.

Answer (score 4):

For those who still interested, I wrote a drop-in @pytest.mark.parametrize replacement for unittest.TestCase: https://github.com/MrMrRobat/parametrize

```
import unittest

from parametrize import parametrize

class FixtureTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @parametrize(
        "test_input,expected",
        [
            ("3+5", 8),
            ("2+4", 6),
            ("6*9", 42),
        ]
    )
    def test_1(self, test_input, expected):
        self.assertEqual(eval(test_input), expected)
```

`$ pytest test.py::FixtureTestCase::test_1`

```
Test session starts (platform: darwin, Python 3.9.4, pytest 6.2.4, pytest-sugar 0.9.4)
plugins: sugar-0.9.4, cov-2.11.1, mock-3.6.0
collecting ... 
 test.py ✓✓                                                       67% ██████▋   

―――――――――――――――――――――――― FixtureTestCase.test_1[6*9-42] ――――――――――――――――――――――――

self = <test.FixtureTestCase testMethod=test_1[6*9-42]>, test_input = '6*9'
expected = 42

    @parametrize(
        "test_input,expected",
        [
            ("3+5", 8),
            ("2+4", 6),
            ("6*9", 42),
        ]
    )
    def test_1(self, test_input, expected):
>       self.assertEqual(eval(test_input), expected)
E       AssertionError: 54 != 42

test.py:16: AssertionError

 test.py ⨯                                                       100% ██████████
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test.py::FixtureTestCase::test_1[6*9-42] - AssertionError: 54 != 42

Results (0.09s):
       2 passed
       1 failed
         - test.py:7 FixtureTestCase.test_1[6*9-42]
```

Comment: Dear @Bobronium, does it work with unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase classes?

Answer (score 2):

Finally and considering the reply by @Brendan Abel and comments I managed to succeed in what I was intended to do by doing:

```
class TestCase(object):

    @parameterized.expand([
    ("negative", -1.5, -2.0),
    ("integer", 1, 1.0),
    ("large fraction", 1.6, 1),
    ])
    def test_floor(self, name, input, expected):
        assert_equal(math.floor(input), expected)


    @parameterized.expand([
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
    ])
    def test_1(self, a, b):
        assert_equal(eval(a), b)
```

Then I am able to execute the tests by the [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) command:

```
  nosetests -v --with-id class.py
```