# pytest.mark.parametrize with django.test.SimpleTestCase

Tags: django, pytest

I am using pytest 3.2.2 and Django 1.11.5 on Python 3.6.2 on Windows.

The following code

```
import django.test
import pytest

class ParametrizeTest:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param", ["a", "b"])
    def test_pytest(self, param):
        print(param)
        assert False
```

works as expected:

> scratch_test.py::ParametrizeTest::test_pytest[a] FAILED
>   scratch_test.py::ParametrizeTest::test_pytest[b] FAILED

But as soon as I change it to use Django's `SimpleTestCase`,
like this:

```
class ParametrizeTest(django.test.SimpleTestCase):
   ...
```

it fails with

> TypeError: test_pytest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param'

Can anybody explain why? And what to do against it?
(I actually even need to use `django.test.TestCase` and access the database.)

I have the following pytest plugins installed:

> plugins: random-0.2, mock-1.6.2, django-3.1.2, cov-2.5.1

but turning any one of them (or all of them) off via `-p no:random` etc. does not help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462680/674039

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Django test class is a `unittest.TestCase` subclass. 
 Parametrization is unsupported and this is documented under the section [**pytest features in `unittest.TestCase` subclasses**](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses):

---

The following pytest features do not work, and probably never will due to different design philosophies:

- Fixtures (except for autouse fixtures)
- **Parametrization**
- Custom hooks

---

If you need parametrized tests and pytest runner, your best bet is to abandon the unittest style - this means move the setup/teardown into fixtures (`pytest-django` plugin has already implemented the hard parts for you), and use module level functions for your tests.

Answer (score 17):

## Use @pytest.mark.django_db

Thanks, wim, for that helpful answer. RTFM, once again.

For clarity, here is the formulation that *will* work (equivalent to a test inheriting from `TestCase`, not just `SimpleTestCase`).
Make sure you have `pytest-django` installed and then do:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
class ParametrizeTest:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param", ["a", "b"])
    def test_pytest(self, param):
        print(param)
        assert False
```

(BTW: Funnily, one reason why I originally decided to use `pytest` was that
the idea of using plain test functions instead of test methods appealed to me;
I like lightweight approaches.
But now I almost exclusively use test classes and methods anyway,
because I prefer the explicit grouping of tests they provide.)

Comment: This seems like it should work, but how do I also make use of Django fixtures to set up the database?