# Marks a method with parameters as a test and provides inline arguments on unittest

Tags: python

I have the following test case which checking `identity(x)` function (for simplicity identity return the input parameter)

```
class test_new_functions(unittest.TestCase):
    # (1, 1)
    # (2, 2)
    def test_identity(self, input, expectedOutput):
        self.assertEqual(identity(input), expectedOutput)
...
```

I want to change it to something like the following `C#` example:

```
public class MySpec
    {
        [TestCase( "1", 1, TestName = "test-1")]
        [TestCase("2", 2, TestName = "test-2")]
        [TestCase("3", 3, TestName = "test-3")]

        public void TestingParsing(string input, int output)
        {
           Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(input), output);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Is it possible in some way on `Python 2.7`?

Comment: Side note: Python 2.7 is dead. Don’t use that ancient version anymore.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Thanks, Its really old production service version, need to upgrade it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) but it requires you to run your test through `pytest` over `unittest`

If you don't want that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462680/13665895) is a similar question with an equivalent to `pytest.mark.parametrize` for unittest