# pytest parameterization indirectly when using unittest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I'm using the python unittest and pytest frameworks together.
I ran into a case where I have a fixture that generates signed header tokens, which I'm trying to mock locally. So I want to create a fixture that I can pass a payload to when the test runs. It doesn't seem like I can do it with pytest and unittest together, however.

```
pytest.fixture
def gen_headers(value):
  return "hey bud, you got a nice header!" + value["fake_head"]


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

  @pytest.mark.parametrize("gen_headers", [{"fake_head": "hi :)"}], indirect=True)
    def test_func(self, gen_headers):
        do_ya_thing = api.request("get", headers=gen_headers)
        ...
```

the test fails `TypeError: ...  missing 1 required positional argument: ...`

I tried using the paramterized python package, but I dont think it supports passing a custom input to the fixture at run time (test time), which is what I'm looking to do, since the thing being returned in `gen_headers` may change.

Comment: Here's a similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561843/py-test-parametrize-test-cases-from-classes

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily combine parameterized fixtures with unittest. Any reason not to use pytest directly here?

With pytest alone you can easily gain access to the params using the request fixture.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def gen_headers(request):
    return "hey bud, you got a nice header!" + request.param["fake_head"]


class TestWithFixtures:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "gen_headers",
        [
            {"fake_head": "hi :)"},
            {"fake_head": "bye :("}
        ],
        indirect=True
    )
    def test_func(self, gen_headers):
        print(gen_headers)
```

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test.py::TestWithFixtures::test_func[gen_headers0] 
test.py::TestWithFixtures::test_func[gen_headers1] 

============================== 2 passed in 0.02s ==============================

PASSED                [ 50%]hey bud, you got a nice header!hi :)
PASSED                [100%]hey bud, you got a nice header!bye :(
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! By the way, when you parameterize the test, does the mean the test will execute for each param in the list?

Comment: @dataviews Yep. The tests will be restarted for each individual item. The lifetime of each fixture used would depend on the value used in the scope, but by default the scope is set to setup/teardown on each run.

Comment: So should I not use parameterize if I just need to dynamically set something that the fixture will return, only 1 time for a given test case?

Comment: @dataviews if the testcase is only parameterized once, there's not much point to making it dynamically set. Just put the constant in the fixture itself.