# TypeError: TestViews.test_fails() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param'

Tags: python, django, selenium, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to run tests on a Django app using selenium + pytest which according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase:%7E:text=%2C%20for%20example.-,LiveServerTestCase,-%C2%B6), below should work.

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


class TestViews(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.driver = Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, 'driver'):
            cls.driver.quit()
            super().tearDownClass()

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('param', ['param1', 'param2'])
    def test_fails(self, param):
        pass
```

However, I get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Error
TypeError: TestViews.test_fails() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param'
  
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 1):

`StaticLiveServerTestCase` inherits `unittest.TestCase`, which means that you cannot use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to expand your test. Fortunately, you can use `parameterized` instead.

See [Does pytest parametrized test work with unittest class based tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182251/does-pytest-parametrized-test-work-with-unittest-class-based-tests/52062473#52062473) for the related question.

And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062473/7058266 for the workaround.

Here's what your code would look like after swapping out `@pytest.mark.parametrize` with `parameterized`:

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

class TestViews(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.driver = Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, 'driver'):
            cls.driver.quit()
            super().tearDownClass()

    @parameterized.expand([
        ['param1'],
        ['param2'],
    ])
    def test_fails(self, param):
        pass
```