# How to run unit test with fixtures from IDE, interpreter or line-by-line

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Pytest fixtures seems like a very powerful tool. I never used them for now, except ones with `autouse=True` because a test function defined with `fixture1` and `fixture2` can not be run anymore as:

```
from module.tests import test_with_fixtures

test_with_fixtures()
```

It's now missing 2 required positional arguments, `fixture1` and `fixture2`. And since you can not call fixture directly.. what is the usual way to work with unit test defined with fixtures?

Comment: unittest.TestCase and pytest fixtures cannot be combined. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187731/7058266 Is that what you're asking? There are alternatives though to accomplish the same goals.

Comment: No, because I'm using test functions and not class. e.g. if I have a function signature `test_something()`, without arguments and fixture; it's very simple to improve and/or debug because you can import `test_something` and run it in an IDE in debug mode, line by line.